# How to identify a window that has already been enumerated?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a process that enumerates windows with `EnumWindows`. The EnumWindowsProc creates a thread that works on the window handle for a long time.

The main thread periodically calls `EnumWindows` to check if there are any new windows to enumerate. I need to be able to identify the windows that have already been enumerated so that more threads wont be recreated for those windows that have already been enumerated.

I've just been changing the title bar of the windows to identify those that have been enumerated before, but some background windows like GDI+ helper window, User Session helper window, cant be renamed, and so memory is wasted creating threads for them on every `EnumWindows` call. I could hardcode the program to identify those names, but that doesn't seem ideal.

Could someone tell me if there is a better way to do this? I don't need to process those non-visible windows, only those that can be seen (like on the taskbar). Thanks for reading!

Comment: Are you enumerating more than just your own windows?  A [mre] showing just your enumeration code (no threads, no processing) would make things clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out invisible windows by checking their `WS_VISIBLE` style:

```
if(GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_VISIBLE)
    ; // the window is visible
```

To determine if you already have a thread processing that window, you can keep a hash table of the known windows:

```
std::unordered_set<HWND> S;

// when new window is found:
S.insert(hwnd);

// when done processing the window:
S.erase(hwnd);

// to check if the window is known:
if(S.find(hwnd) == S.end())
    ; // the window is not in the set
```

The window handles are system global and do not change during the lifetime of the window. However they may be eventually reused if the windows are being created and destroyed -- but AFAIK there's no way around it.

Comment: You could store the window handle and the ID of its owning process and thread. All of them can be reused, so in theory you could eventually hit the same combination happening again, but the odds are drastically reduced.

Answer (score 1):

> The main thread periodically calls EnumWindows to check if there are any new windows to enumerate.

I would suggest using `SetWindowsHookEx()` instead to install a global `WH_CBT` or `WH_SHELL` hook to tell you when new windows are created/activated.

> I've just been changing the title bar of the windows to identify those that have been enumerated before.

A less intrusive approach might be to use `SetProp()` to store a custom marker inside of each window, and then you can look for that marker later.  You will have to call `RemoveProp()` on each window before it is destroyed, but you can use a hook for that, too.

Or, you can simply store each `HWND` in your own list, and then check that list before adding any new `HWND`.  You will still have to use a hook to detect when each `HWND` is destroyed so you can remove it from your list.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reading and providing your insights! I'll be trying the method of storing the HWNDS into a list and checking it, as mentioned by yakov as well. I'm curious about the SetWindowsHookEx method, how do I detect new windows? Are you suggesting i inject the dll into all the processes to check for ````WM_CREATE?````

Comment: Read the documentation for [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw). If you use a `WH_CBT` hook, for instance, then your [`CBTProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644977(v=vs.85)) callback will receive various notifications, such as `HCBT_CREATEWND` and `HCBT_DESTROYWND`. And yes, you would implement your hook callback in a DLL, which `SetWindowsHookEx()` will then inject into every process for you